# Convert for loop to recursion to deep copy a nested list

Tags: python, recursion

Need your help in converting this function to use only recursion. Currently it's using a for loop and recursion but it needs to use only recursion.
The function gets a list or a nested list and needs to return a copied list (deep copy!).

And I **can not** `import deepcopy from copy` or use list comprehension.

```py
def my_deepcopy(nested_list: List[Any]) -> List[Any]:
    results = []
    for item in nested_list:
        if not isinstance(item, list):
            results.append(item)
        else:
            results.append(my_deepcopy(item))
    return results
```

Comment: I'm curious why you can not use loop?

Comment: This is what I was asked for. If I could I would use it but unfortunately I can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to turn an iterative function into a recursive function is to have a base case for an empty list, and then add the recursive result from the first list item to the results for the remaining list items.  E.g.:

```
>>> def list_deepcopy(item):
...     if not isinstance(item, list) or not item:
...         return item
...     return [list_deepcopy(item[0])] + list_deepcopy(item[1:])
...
>>> a = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]]
>>> b = list_deepcopy(a)
>>> a[0] *= 10
>>> a[2][0] *= 10
>>> a[2][2][0] *= 10
>>> a
[10, 2, [30, 4, [50, 6]]]
>>> b
[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I forgot to mention I can not use list comprehension also. I'm gonna update the post

Comment: @AviDoe There is no list comprehension here...

Comment: Thank you! But now I wonder if there is a way to not use slicing on the list and achieve the same thing. If you have any idea how to do that I'd be glad to hear. Nevertheless your solution helped me

Answer (score 1):

Method without slicing:

```
def list_deepcopy(lst, start=0):
    if not isinstance(lst, list):
        return lst
    if start == len(lst):
        return []

    return [list_deepcopy(lst[start])] + list_deepcopy(lst, start + 1)
```

Some test:

```
>>> a = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]
>>> b = list_deepcopy(a)
>>> a
[1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]
>>> b
[1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> for i in range(5):
...     reduce(getitem, repeat(1, i), a)[0] *= 10
... 
>>> a
[10, [20, [30, [40, [50]]]]]
>>> b
[1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]]]
```